# Use codecs to read file with correct encoding: TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I need to read from a file, linewise. Also also need to make sure the encoding is correctly handled.

I wrote the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

import codecs

filename = "something.x10"

f = open(filename, 'r')
fEncoded = codecs.getreader("ISO-8859-15")(f)

totalLength = 0
for line in fEncoded:
  totalLength+=len(line)

print("Total Length is "+totalLength)
```

This code does not work on all files, on some files I get a

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in fEncoded:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 623, in __next__
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 536, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/codecs.py", line 480, in read
    data = self.bytebuffer + newdata
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Im using python 3.3 and the script must work with this python version.

What am I doing wrong, I was not able to find out which files work and which not, even some plain ASCII files fail.

Comment: You say some plain ASCII files fail. Do you have one that is short enough to post here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening the file in non-binary mode. If you read from it, you get a string decoded according to your default encoding (http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open%20builtin#open).

codec's StreamReader needs a bytestream (http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs#codecs.StreamReader)

So this should work:

```
import codecs

filename = "something.x10"

f = open(filename, 'rb')
f_decoded = codecs.getreader("ISO-8859-15")(f)

totalLength = 0
for line in f_decoded:
   total_length += len(line)

print("Total Length is "+total_length)
```

or you can use the encoding parameter on `open`:

```
 f_decoded = open(filename, mode='r', encoding='ISO-8859-15')
```

The reader returns decoded data, so I fixed your variable name. Also, consider [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as a guide for formatting and coding style.